# Spectral energy distribution fitting tools or routines

Tags: software

I have observed magnitudes and fluxes for an object in different wavelengths from optical to mm. Now I need a tool, routine or something like that to fit a [spectral energy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_energy_distribution) (SED) and derive some physical parameters from the fit.

I'm looking for a ready tool which can be run remotely or installed locally.

Mind you, I'm aware of this: http://caravan.astro.wisc.edu/protostars/

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Thanks for the edit, it reads much better:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly are, but it depends on what the object is?

For example, I have used the `flared disk' model of Dullemond Dominik & Natta (2001) to model the SED of hot dust around a sgB[e] star

http://www.mpia.de/homes/dullemon/ppdisks.html

where at optical wavelengths emission is dominated by a ~25kK stellar source but at 10 microns it is due to hot dust (~1000K) that forms in a equatorial disk around the central B[e] star and a cold dust component (~100K) that dominates the long-wavelength emission. CMFGEN will also model the SED for hot stars, LBVs, Wolf-Rayets etc., but the underlying physical conditions are very different, while a QSO would be very different again - and it's really the geometry, distribution and composition of material that affect the SED of an object, so different objects require different models. Short of the basic approach of fitting one or more Black Body models, I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all approach.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. The objects that I'm dealing with are Young Stellar Objects, particularly Class 0/I and maybe Class II. I could in principle test the model for some of my TTau candidates where I expect conditions are "right" for the specific case.